# Fresh Wordpress Install on Azure Fails to Update to 3.7

Tags: wordpress, azure

I decided to try out Windows Azure for hosting Wordpress. So i just created a fresh new install of Wordpress from the gallery using the Websites option in Azure.

This is what i get when i try to update to 3.7

```
Downloading update from http://wordpress.org/wordpress-3.7-no-content.zip…
Unpacking the update…
Verifying the unpacked files…
Preparing to install the latest version…
Enabling Maintenance mode…
Copying the required files…
Disabling Maintenance mode…
Could not copy file.: index.php
Installation Failed
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: I am having the same issue. If you look at the php_errors.log file, you may see more details. Mine is complaining of permissions. PHP Warning: copy(C:/DWASFiles/Sites/[site]/VirtualDirectory0/site/wwwroot/index.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\DWASFiles\Sites\[site]\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\wp-admin\includes\class-wp-filesystem-direct.php on line 200 Now just to determine what permissions it needs that it doesn't have.

Comment: Once you figure out the permissions, sounds like a great answer to post. But as it stands, this is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: oops, I should have made that a comment, sorry :(

Comment: Oddly enough,  I went to update my site again today, and it updated successfully with no changes on my end.  I am now running in 3.7 with no issue.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem and got the same error message as Jef. To fix it do the following:

Open wp-config.php and delete/remove/comment out these lines of code:

```
    define('FS_METHOD','direct');
    define('FS_CHMOD_DIR',0777);
    define('FS_CHMOD_FILE',0666);
```

Now add these lines of code:

```
    define('FS_CHMOD_DIR', (0755 & ~ umask()));
    define('FS_CHMOD_FILE', (0644 & ~ umask()));
```

Save and upload wp-config.php. Go to your dashboard and run the update. You will be asked for your ftp user name and password.

Comment: Hi, I tried this out (as I have the same issue as the OP), but unfortunately it did not resolve the issue - the wordpress update system doesn't request credentials.  Using ftp credentials might be a way to go, will be testing this shortly http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_Upgrade_Constants ?

Comment: @StepLocke - did you get this to work? I'm having the same problem a year later, but it is with V4 of WordPress.